# Post Koha Patrons to Koha LMS using php CURL

Tags: php, api, web-services, curl

Trying to post patrons to KOHA LMS but I keep on getting error 400 as depicted below;

```
{
    //Here is missing some code.
    "errors": [{
            "message": "Missing property.",
            "path": "/body/address"
        },
        {
            "message": "Missing property.",
            "path": "/body/category_id"
        },
        {
            "message": "Missing property.",
            "path": "/body/city"
        },
        {
            "message": "Missing property.",
            "path": "/body/library_id"
        },
        {
            "message": "Missing property.",
            "path": "/body/surname"
        }],
    "status": 400
}
```

I have tried all that I could possibly think to maneuver around this error, and there seems to be no concrete documentation on KOHA integration out there.If anyone got it working kindly assist.

Below is part of the code showing the curl code;

```
{
    //Here is missing some code.
    $url2 = "http://example.com:8000/api/v1/patrons";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $data = array(
        'addPatron' => array(
            'address' => "",
            'city' => "",
            'cardnumber' => $num,
            'firstname' => $fname,
            'surname' => $sname,
            'other_name' => $mname,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'email' => $email,
            'category_id' => $category,
            'library_id' => $library_id,
        )
    );


    /*$data = array(                        
                'address' => "",
                'city' => "",
                'cardnumber' => $num,
                'firstname' => $fname,
                'surname' => $sname,
                'other_name' => $mname,
                'phone' => $phone,
                'email' => $email,
                'category_id' => $category,
                'library_id' => $library_id                     
            );*/



    $ch3 = curl_init($url2);

    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username. ":".$password);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Cookie: CGISESSID='.$cookies['CGISESSID'];
    $headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
    $headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $d = curl_exec($ch3);
    curl_close($ch3);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(json_decode($d));
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

The above code basically tries to post the Koha patrons into the Library Management System.So far I was able to GET the patrons.Using the same scenario to post is proving to be difficult.Any help or hint towards the answer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

per the documentation on https://demo.bibkat.no/api/v1/.html#op-post-patrons (you should link to your API's documentation in your question by the way), this API want JSON requests, but you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests with http_build_query()

replace

```
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

with

```
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

and add

```
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
```

also replace

```
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

with

```
    curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

quoting the libcurl CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST documentation @ https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html :

> Many people have wrongly used this option to replace the entire request with their own, including multiple headers and POST contents. While that might work in many cases, it will cause libcurl to send invalid requests and it could possibly confuse the remote server badly. Use CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to set POST data.

also strictly speaking, you should make a bugreport to the api maintainers, the correct response when receiving `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` while expecting JSON is not `Http 400 Bad Request` (albeit it is close), the correct response is

> HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415